# How to add public method to jQuery plugin based on this jQuery plugin pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

How can I add public methods to my custom jQuery plugin which is based on this pattern from **jquery-boilerplate**:
https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-patterns/blob/master/patterns/jquery.extend-skeleton.js

I need to use my plugin and call public method something like this:

```
jQuery('.element').pluginName();

//And now assuming that plugin has a public method `examplePublicMethod`,
//I want to call it like this:
var instance = jQuery('#element').data('pluginName');
instance.examplePublicMethod();
```

Is it possible at all when I use this pattern from the link? Here's the code sample of this pattern:

```
;(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        pluginName: function( options ) {

            this.defaultOptions = {};

            var settings = $.extend({}, this.defaultOptions, options);

            return this.each(function() {

                var $this = $(this);
                //And here is the main code of the plugin
                //...
                //And I'm not sure how to add here a public method
                //that will be accessible from outside the plugin

            });

        }

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is multiple way to do this, but the one I prefer is like that :

```
$.fn.extend({
    pluginName: function( options ) {

        this.defaultOptions = {};

        var settings = $.extend({}, this.defaultOptions, options);

        return this.each(function() {

            var $this = $(this);

            //Create a new Object in the data.
            $this.data('pluginName', new pluginMethods($this)) //pluginMethod are define below

        });

    }

});

function pluginMethods($el){
    //Keep reference to the jQuery element
    this.$el = $el; 
    //You can define all variable shared between functions here with the keyword `this`
}

$.extend(pluginMethods.prototype, {
    //Here all you methods
    redFont : function(){
        //Simply changing the font color
        this.$el.css('color', 'red')
    }
})


$('#el').pluginName();

//Public method:
var instance = jQuery('#el').data('pluginName');
instance.redFont();
```

The disadvantage with that is pluginMethods is accessible by everyone. But you can solve that by moving it in the same closure that the plugin declaration like that :

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        pluginName: function( options ) {

            this.defaultOptions = {};

            var settings = $.extend({}, this.defaultOptions, options);

            return this.each(function() {

                var $this = $(this);

                $this.data('pluginName', new pluginMethods($this))

            });

        }

    });

    function pluginMethods($el){
        //Keep reference to the jQuery element
        this.$el = $el; 
    }

    $.extend(pluginMethods.prototype, {
        //Here all you methods
        redFont : function(){
            this.$el.css('color', 'red')
        }
    })

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you. Is this way effective (in terms of performance and memory usage)? I will call my plugin on big collections of elements, e.g. `jQuery('.element').pluginName();` there will be dozens of objects with class `.element`. I'm asking because there was another answer here (but looks like it is deleted now, I don't know why) and there was discussion in comments about if this is effective to call constructor many times in a loop. From your example `new pluginMethods($this)` will be called for each element `.element`? Or maybe I should use different plugin pattern for my case?

Comment: @zitix yes it is effective. The other answer was about the same but the object declaration (`pluginMethods` in this case) was inside the `pluginName` function, hence why the debate. Just know that `.data()` return only 1 value, the first one in the stack. That mean you need to loop your stack before doing your call to the function.

Comment: @zitix here a the way you should init you plugin imo. I guess you can read code so it shouldn't be hard to understand : http://jsfiddle.net/mc3VT/

Comment: I have one last question. Can I add public methods directly inside `function pluginMethods($el)` (see `greenFont()` in this fiddle based on your example: http://jsfiddle.net/9UC5y/)? I've checked and it works correctly but I'm wondering why you are using `$.extend(pluginMethods.prototype, {...});` in your example to add public methods. Is it just for better code organization or is it required for some other reasons?

Comment: @zitix it is not *required* but it is an optimisation. If you have not using prototype, you can reassigning the function everytime you call your plugin. Declaring it as a prototype allow you to declare it 1 time and sharing among other object declaration. I also personally think using prototype is much cleaner.